# Delete vector object while in for loop [c++]

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, indexing

In my program i have a for loop which updates all the bullets/shots in my game.
It looks like this:

```
for (auto sprite : shots)
{
    sprite->update(shots);
}
```

In the update function from the class, i delete a shot from the shots list if it detects a collision, like this:

```
void Shot::terminate(std::vector<Shot*>& shots)
{
    shots.erase(shots.begin() + index /*index is the elements number in the vector "shots"*/);
}
```

This function "terminate" is called if the `update()` class function detects a collision.
But when a object from the list is deleted while in the for loop; the program crashes "vector subscript out of range". The counter in the for loop should be substracted by 1 every time a object gets deleted but i dont know how to do so in a c++11 for loop. Is it possible to fix my problem?

Comment: What is `index`? Please make a [mre]

Comment: Are you ultimately deleting the sprite from the range based for loop?

Comment: yes, im disappearing it completely.

Comment: That's UB, you can't modify a range that you do a range-for loop over.

Comment: This seems like a design issue. Why is `Shot` responsible for removing itself(?) from some vector? My first thought is to make it have some `isPresentOnScreen()` function which could be used in `std::remove_if` after the `update` loop.

Comment: @S.M. Yes it does answer my question